# How to show only the author's posts?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm setting up a client area in wordpress, and I'm going to use the author part to choose the client that is associated with the project.

In the posts grid part on the frontend, I would like only the posts of the current user to appear.

That is, each user will only view their own posts.

I found some similar articles but nothing about what I really need.

Answer (score 0):

You can create shortcode easily like this:

```
add_shortcode('currentauthorpost', 'ak_currentauthorpost');
function ak_currentauthorpost(){

if ( is_user_logged_in() ):

    global $current_user;
    wp_get_current_user();
    $author_query = array( 'post_type'=>'post', 'posts_per_page' => '-1','author' => $current_user->ID);
    $author_posts = new WP_Query($author_query);
    while($author_posts->have_posts()) : $author_posts->the_post();
    ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>       
    <?php           
    endwhile;

else :

    echo "not logged in";

endif;

}
```

you can use simply this shortcode

```
[currentauthorpost]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! In my case, I'm using Elementor's Loop for the posts grid. Is it still possible to somehow use this shortcode with Elementor?

Comment: you can use elementor shortcode widget and put shortcode there.